# Remap FN key to OPTION key

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I just got a new [keyboard](http://cougargaming.com/us/products/keyboards/attackx3/).  How can I remap the FN key on only this external keyboard to option?

So far I've played around with [karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) but haven't had success.

Answer (score 1):

One Excellent third party tool that can make amazing edits to the keyboard mapping is named [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

To accomplish option and function key changes, create a filter for the external keyboard and adjust the modifier keys.

Prerequisites: external keyboard

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Launch EventViewer</kbd>
5. Hit the tab *Devices*
6. Make a note of the vendor and product ID of the external keyboard:

   [image]
7. Hit the tab *Main*
8. Enter the (PC-)Ctrl-key, (PC-)Fn-key and the (PC-)Alt-key and make a note of the "event names/miscs":

   [image]
9. Close the EventViewer
10. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
11. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
12. Enter the customized keycode and replace the vendor name, the product name, the vendor and product ID by IDs and names found above as well as the "names/miscs" of the events (= KeyCode).

    ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
      <devicevendordef>
        <vendorname>Cougar</vendorname>
        <vendorid>0x05ac</vendorid>
      </devicevendordef>
      <deviceproductdef>
        <productname>ATTACKX3</productname>
        <productid>0x0256</productid>
      </deviceproductdef>
      <item>
        <name>Function to Option for ATTACKX3</name>
        <identifier>private.fn2optExtK</identifier>
        <device_only>DeviceVendor::Cougar, DeviceProduct::ATTACKX3</device_only>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Fn, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
      </item>
    </root>
    ```

    Depending on your findings in the Event Viewer you may have to remap (PC-)keys to Control_L and Command_L also.
13. Save the file
14. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
15. Hit the ReloadXML button
16. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, I'm failing at step 8.  When I press the FN key I see no events in the EventViewer main tab.  (I do see events correctly when I press CMD and CTRL).  So I think the FN key isn't mapped to anything.

Comment: @StevenWexler Did you disable *Hide ignorable Events* in Event Viewer -> Preferences?

Comment: Yep, that option is disabled.