# Reprogram / Remap a Button on Apple Keyboard to send a sequence of keystrokes

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I am seeking help with my iMac.

I am an independent Nasdaq day-trader using Trading View as an analytical platform on a daily basis. If it is possible, I would like to reprogram the <kbd>Fn</kbd>
button (or any other button) on my Apple keyboard that when pressed, it’s initiates a string of letters.

In this example, I would like it to input the letters: <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> as these (2) buttons are what’s required draw a “trend-line” on the platform.  Instead of me manually having to click on the trend-line or pressing <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> simultaneously, is there any way I can reprogram the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button on my keyboard so it initiate’s these letters?

It’s predominately to save time and also because it’s quite awkward pressing the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd>  buttons together with one hand. I know it’s such a small thing for everyone else, but believe it or not it would be a tremendous help to my workflow.

Comment: Does this command have a menu item in the app? What macOS are you running?

Comment: Also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/452082/489896 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/229381/489896 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/374637/489896

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t remapping of a key on the keyboard but rather assigning a *macro* to a key.

As a project, I attached a second (Logitech) keyboard to my Mac to act as a makeshift “board” of sorts that autmated several actions.  One of these was issuing commands in Think-or-Swim (TD Ameritrade) for pulling up charts and entering orders.

There are a few tools you can use.  All are paid apps, but they each have trial periods (ControllerMate is unlimited, but limits the number of actions)

- ControllerMate.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287612/119271) for more details.
- [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html).
- [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/).

In my experimentation, I was able to program buttons on the second keyboard to launch new instances of Firefox with a specific profile, issue several key presses in a certain sequence (ToS), and even run AppleScripts.  It’s not required to have a second keyboard (you can remap any key on your existing keyboard), I was trying to emulate products like the [X-Keys](https://xkeys.com/) products.

I attempted to do this with AppleScript, but it tended to break when the software was updated.  I found both ControllerMate and USB Overdrive to meet the requirements perfectly. I’ve not used Keyboard Maestro.

Currently, I have a 10-key USB keypad that I assigned macros  in Lightroom to automate repetitive tasks.  I abandoned the ToS project because I’m not a trader.  20-30 trades a month was too little for the effort required to maintain this.